# Simplify logging used in pytest

Tags: python, macos, logging, pytest, python-logging

I wanted to simplify my current logging system for my program testing. I'm using pytest and python 3.10.8 default logging module. I'm not sure if this is even possible from what I've seen online. Thought I'd ask in case anyone knows if this is possible.
Basically I run the pytest command and while the test is run, its also outputting to a log file that I've created at "../logs/test.log"

**pyproject.toml:**

```
[tool.pytest.ini_options]
log_cli = true
log_cli_level = "CRITICAL"
log_cli_format = "%(messages)s"
log_file = "../logs/test.log"
log_file_level = "INFO"
log_file_format = "\n%(asctime)s: [%(levelname)s]\n\t%(message)s (%(filename)s:%(lineno)d)"
log_file_date_format = "%Y-%m-%d @ %H:%M:%S %Z"
```

---

**What's used in the code:**

```
import logging

def test_common_count(setUp):
    logging.info("MOST COMMON WORDS AND COUNTS TEST: Using the the test sting. Test string is: %s.", setUp['test_string'])
    text = combine(setUp['test_string'])
    assert text == setUp['expected_string']
    try:
        ... Something something something python code ...
        logging.info("MOST COMMON WORDS AND COUNTS TEST: Result element types and values are as espected. Result is: %s.", result)
    except:
        logging.error("MOST COMMON WORDS AND COUNTS TEST: Result was incorrect. Result is: %s.", result)
        fail()
```

---

**Current log file created:**

```
2023-06-21 @ 11:46:08 EDT: [INFO]
    Uploading a txt file (tests_app.py:19)

2023-06-21 @ 11:46:08 EDT: [INFO]
    Text file name: test.txt (fake_app.py:29)

2023-06-21 @ 11:46:08 EDT: [INFO]
    Uploading a PDF file (tests_app.py:32)

2023-06-21 @ 11:46:08 EDT: [INFO]
    PDF file name: test.pdf (fake_app.py:37)

2023-06-21 @ 11:57:52 EDT: [INFO]
    HYPHEN REMOVAL TEST: Using the the test sting. Test string is: The dog- -s ran down the road to see the other dogs. (tests_manipulate.py:22)

2023-06-21 @ 11:57:52 EDT: [INFO]
    HYPHEN REMOVAL TEST: Result is as expected. Result is: The dogs ran down the road to see the other dogs. (tests_manipulate.py:27)

2023-06-21 @ 11:57:52 EDT: [INFO]
    MOST COMMON WORDS AND COUNTS TEST: Using the the test sting. Test string is: The dog- -s ran down the road to see the other dogs. (tests_manipulate.py:33)

2023-06-21 @ 11:57:52 EDT: [INFO]
    MOST COMMON WORDS AND COUNTS TEST: Result element types and values are as espected. Result is: [('dogs', 2), ('road', 1)]. (tests_manipulate.py:43)
```

---

**Desired log file:**

```
2023-06-21 @ 11:46:08 EDT: [INFO]
    Uploading a txt file (tests_app.py:19)

2023-06-21 @ 11:46:08 EDT: [INFO]
    Uploaded text file: test.txt (fake_app.py:29)

2023-06-21 @ 11:46:08 EDT: [INFO]
    Uploading a PDF file (tests_app.py:32)

2023-06-21 @ 11:46:08 EDT: [INFO]
    Uploaded pdf file: test.pdf (fake_app.py:37)

================================= App tests finished =================================

2023-06-21 @ 11:57:52 EDT: [INFO]
    HYPHEN REMOVAL TEST: Using the the test sting. Test string is: The dog- -s ran down the road to see the other dogs. (tests_manipulate.py:22)

2023-06-21 @ 11:57:52 EDT: [INFO]
    HYPHEN REMOVAL TEST: Result is as expected. Result is: The dogs ran down the road to see the other dogs. (tests_manipulate.py:27)

2023-06-21 @ 11:57:52 EDT: [INFO]
    MOST COMMON WORDS AND COUNTS TEST: Using the the test sting. Test string is: The dog- -s ran down the road to see the other dogs. (tests_manipulate.py:33)

2023-06-21 @ 11:57:52 EDT: [INFO]
    MOST COMMON WORDS AND COUNTS TEST: Result element types and values are as espected. Result is: [('dogs', 2), ('road', 1)]. (tests_manipulate.py:43)

================================= Manipulation tests finished =================================
```

---

I don't think it would be relevant to this question but i'm including it incase it's helpful.

**Pytest session:**

**command:**
python -m pytest tests_*.py -s

```
==================================================================================== test session starts ====================================================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.10.8, pytest-7.3.2, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /usr/home/Desktop/Projects/extractor
configfile: pyproject.toml
plugins: instafail-0.5.0
collected 7 items                                                                                                                                                                          

tests_app.py::test_upload_textFile PASSED
tests_app.py::test_upload_pdfFile PASSED
tests_app.py::test_upload_text PASSED
tests_app.py::test_fileContentType_fail PASSED
tests_app.py::test_fileUpload_fail PASSED
tests_manipulate.py::test_remove_hyphen PASSED
tests_manipulate.py::test_common_count PASSED

==================================================================================== 7 passed in 5.35s ====================================================================================
```

Comment: This should be pretty simple via a single fixture inside of `conftest.py`.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few concepts here that are conflated. Let's take a look:

A quick option, in line with what you have already, would be to use a fixture.

In conftest.py:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def log_module_conclusion(request):
    yield
    logging.info('='*10 + f'{request.module} finished' + '='*10)
```

In pytest.ini

```
usefixtures = 
    log_module_conclusion
```

I'm not a fan of this for a few reasons. Pytest has it's own reporting capabilities that you can modify with hooks. Using fixtures (which are intended for test setup and tear down) with the python logging module is not supported and may break in future. You may have started using logging because you found print is suppressed, that should give you the hint the Pytest has ideas around how this should be handled. The whole premise of live reporting results is heading in the wrong direction. Test asserts should be written to give you all the info you need. Also, in the event of a pass 'Everything is ok' alarms are just going to be a distraction. Less is more likely to be maintainable, useful and be run.

Here's an example of a simple test with simple asserts and using  pytests features. If this fails, pytest will show the inputs. If someone comes across this in 2 years, they'll understand the focus.

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('test_string,result', [
    ('dogs dogs road', [('dogs', 2), ('road', 1)]),
    ('r rabbit rabbits', [('r', 1), ('rabbit', 1), ('rabbits', 1)]),
])
def test_common_count(test_string, result):
    assert combine(test_string) == result
```